# Datastore App Engine quering ancestor python

Tags: python, google-app-engine, google-cloud-datastore

Hello I'm new on Datastore and on Python and I have a basic question but it can help me to understand more the Google cloud.

I have 4 entities and let's say I have a parent (match) with children : team, player and event.

```
class Team(ndb.Model):
    d_name = ndb.StringProperty()
    d_side = ndb.StringProperty()

class Player(ndb.Model):
    d_name = ndb.StringProperty()
    date_of_birth = ndb.StringProperty()
    d_position = ndb.StringProperty()
    d_teamKey = ndb.StringProperty()


class Match(ndb.Model):
    d_competition_name = ndb.StringProperty()
    d_date = ndb.StringProperty()
    d_pool = ndb.StringProperty()
    d_season = ndb.StringProperty()
    d_team1Key = ndb.StringProperty()
    d_team2Key = ndb.StringProperty()
    d_winning_teamKey = ndb.StringProperty()
    d_match_id = ndb.StringProperty()
    d_match_day = ndb.IntegerProperty()

class Event(ndb.Expando):
    d_teamKey = ndb.StringProperty()
    d_playerKey = ndb.StringProperty()
```

I know that the query if I want all the matchs day 4 is :

```
q = ndb.gql("SELECT * FROM Match WHERE d_match_day = 4")
```

But how can I seach all the players in theses match's children so that I have all the players who have played during the day 4 ?

Thank you !

Answer (score 1):

Add another property to `Match`:  A `StructuredProperty`, which is a list of Players (and/or Teams):

```
Players = ndb.StructuredProperty(Player)
Teams =   ndb.StructuredProperty(Team)
```

Then, you can query for `4` and pull the list of Players and/or Teams.

Answer (score 0):

wait.... you add the player as a child to EACH match he plays?  that seems unefficient design.  A child can only have 1 parent (unless I grossly misunderstood ancestor queries, which is possible, to be fair).

Anyway in one single query I don't think that's doable.  I would start getting the keys from match where d_match_day = 4, and from there do a "select * from Players where match_key = " and use the list you just created.  (you might need to change match_key to match your actual ancestor key, but the jist of it is there)